# Handle unreachable code with code coverage

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

My project has method which checks if a number is within a range

```php
public function foo(int $number): string
{
    // simple logic to get my point across

    if ($number > 0) {
        return 'foo';
    }

    if ($number === 0) {
        return 'bar';
    }

    if ($number < 0) {
        return 'baz';
    }

    assert(0);
}
```

In this simple example, the function will always return at one of the if-statements. However, using `phpunit`s code coverage, the last `assert(0);` is marked as not being executed.

I as a programmer want to specify that if it is not legal for the program to reach this point, and if reached it is fault of the developer. This does however introduce "unreachable" code, such as if the developer has implemented the above logic correctly, will never be executed.

I am not happy with my workaround to reach a 100% code coverage score. This is how I handle it as of now:

```php
public function foo(int $number): string
{
    $value = null;

    if ($number > 0) {
        $value = 'foo';
    }
    if ($number === 0) {
        $value = 'bar';
    }
    if ($number < 0) {
        $value = 'baz';
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Is this the proper way to reach a 100% code coverage score, or should I simply drop that goal and live with an untested `assert(0);` / `throw new Exception()` at the bottom of the code?

Comment: As you've type hinted the parameter as `int $number`, I'm not sure how it can ever get to the `assert()` anyway.

Comment: I understand that `assert(0);` and `throw new Exception();` mean different things. It am unsure if it's better to throw or simple error. That line of code should never be executed, and I put it there to ensure that the program crashes at that point.

Comment: Normally I would use some error handling like this when the user (/programmer) sends some arguments that don't make sense.  For example setting an invalid value based of current circumstances (order 10 when only 2 are in stock for example).  In your case, I can't see how an int (as defined by the type hint) does not fit into the three categories you already cater for.

Comment: @NigelRen Exactly. Until the logic is modified the `assert(0);` is unreachable. My question is regarding how to handle situations like this where we (human) know 100% the `assert(0);` will never be executed, but the code coverage says we have untouched code.

Comment: Your assert is "dead code".  It can't be reached by any program execution.  Code Coverage tells you what code has been executed; it can only tell you that for "live code".  What I would do in this case is change the assert(0) to a special function you invent called "deadcode()".    Then you can simply ignore any noncovered "deadcode" and feel good about it.